# 質問に対して、反対票を入れる評価基準はありますか？

Tags: 討議, 投票の仕方

以下の質問のうち、疑問点を絞って課題としてみます
[このサイトおかしい [改善待ち]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12287/%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%84)

> 知恵袋のように回答が既にあればまだしも、 スタックオーバーフローはいくつかの質問に おいて質問を制限しすぎているように感じます。**また、安易にマイナス票が投じられやすい反面質問文を改善する為のコメントが残されない傾向があります。**

以下の質問が実例です
[leap_year.javaのエラー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12207/leap-year-java%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC)

はっきりと言っておきますと、ここには明らかな問題があります
多くのマイナス評価の質問では、マイナス票が投じられている理由が明示されていません。たとえ閲覧者が自らの基準で反対票を入れたとしても質問者はその理由がコメントで示されないため質問の改善ができません。これは質問者を委縮させる結果となり、利用者の減少につながるのではないでしょうか？いや、まあ減少したとしても私らは他の質問サイト使うだけですが（笑）

ちなみにredditというインターネット掲示板には、スタックオーバーフローのような賛成票・反対票を投じるシステムが存在しますが、反対票を入れる場合のルールがあります。
[レディケット（Redditのエチケット）](http://www.reddit.com/wiki/reddiquette)

いろいろありますがとりあえず一例：

> ・Consider posting constructive criticism / an explanation when you
>   downvote something, and do so carefully and tactfully.

**・投稿するときは建設的な批判を心がける / 何かに反対票を投じるときは説明し、上手に慎重に**

Comment: 評価基準よりどちらかというと「マイナス票するときはコメントで説明すべき」というのが主題と読んだのですがそれで大丈夫でしょうか．もしそうなら related （しばしば問題になっているようです）: [Encouraging people to explain downvotes - Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135), [Am I still supposed to explain my downvotes or not? - Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081), etc. 現時点でもマイナス投票入れるときには一応コメントを促す表示は出ますね．

Comment: エラーメッセージ丸投げ・コード書いてくれといった類の質問に、「この質問には解決しようと努力した跡がみられない・実用的ではない・分かりにくい」(downvoteのpopup説明)を押すのは妥当ですし、理由がそれならいちいち説明する必要もないでしょう。この質問では、7月9日 10:17のコメントで諦められてる感が…

Comment: @moccos 私はその意見は賛成できないです。その言説自体が玄人的ユーザの考えであると思います、つまりすでにスタックオーバーフローのやり方を理解しているハイコンテキストな意識をもったユーザの考えです。せめて、ここでの質問の仕方をどうするべきか教えるリンクを投稿すべきではないでしょうか。

Comment: @panzer_jagdiron 質問の通算がマイナス評価になったときに、自動的にその手のリンクが出ると良いかもしれませんね(投稿者だけでも)。毎回個別に誰かが同じようなことを投稿しなければいけないなら、よくないシステムです

Comment: 正直、コメント無しのマイナス票が大量に投じられて当然のような質問の気がします。@panzer_jagdironさんならなんというコメント付けてあげるのが良いと思いますか？自分がコメントするなら、『初めてのJava系の本を1冊読んだら解決するよ。』くらいしか書きようが無い気がするんですが...そして、そのレベルの事が分からないような質問って事は、本を読む、internetで『Java入門』で検索して学んでみるという最低限の努力すらしてないような方だと受け止めてしまいます。そしてコメント無しのマイナス票を入れたくなるような気がします。ｗ

Answer (score 12, accepted):

英語版でもこの話を良くします。マイナス票が好きな投稿者はいませんが、マイナス票は当サイトに必要な機能です。当質問を見て、改善できる点を把握し、同じような質問を同対応すべきかを討議しましょう。

#### 投票の必要性

ヤフー知恵袋は2005年からあります。スタック・オーバーフローは3年後の2008年です。スタック・オーバーフローはネット上での一番大きなプログラミングQ&Aサイトになった理由は3つあります：

1. Q&Aの高いスタンダードを維持することで、回答が探しやすい
2. 質問にタグをつける・クローズさせることで将来のユーザーに従来の質問が探しやすい
3. 高い質問の質で回答できるユーザーが残る

問題を解決するのも大事ですが、解決しながら当サイトの特徴を忘れてはいけません。現在の投稿者を考えるだけではなく、将来の利用者も考えないといけません。

#### 当質問への疑問点

[指摘された質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12207/leap-year-java%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC) は -7 までなるべきと言いませんが、そのままで良い質問とも言えますか？

1. 問題を明確に定義していますか？
2. 問題を解決するために今まで試したことは説明していますか？
3. 同じ問題のある方に探しやすいですか？

「どこがおかしいのでしょうか？」は問題提議ではありません。何のアウトプットを期待していますか？現在のアウトプットとどう違うですか？その二つを説明すれば、期待している回答がよりわかりやすくなります。

エラーしか出なかったら、エラーを解決するために何をしましたか？他のコードも試していますか？解決するには今まで何を試したかを説明すれば、回答者がより簡単に回答を探せます。

将来のユーザーにとって探しやすいですか？グーグルで検索するためのキーワードが入っていますか？コードをそのままコピペするだけでは検索で探しにくくなります（特にそのコードはエラーしか発生していない場合）。言葉で何をしようとしているかを説明すれば、コードのコピペだけより探しやすいです。

当サイトのヘルプセンターでは「[良い質問をするには?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)」にこのようなアドバイスを与えています。

#### このような質問をどう改善するべき？

この質問の中に良い質問が入っていると思います。問題は現在の形では多くのユーザーがそのいい質問が見えません。

見えないからマイナス票をするべきではないと思います。

[質問内容の明確化のためのコメント(以降、クラリコメント)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12207/leap-year-java%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC#comment11023_12207) を投稿したらやさしいです。[編集で読みやすくする](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/12207/revisions) のもいいです。

当サイトの一つの特徴は皆様が上のことができます。編集を推奨できますし、コメントで質問内容のを明確化するのもできます。**自分の行動で投稿を改善することができます**。

改善することで質問が探しやすくなり、現在の評価は -7 であっても、ネット上での一番いい解決であれば1年後には +10 になることもあります。

#### サマリー

いいリソースになるため、質問の質を確保するのが大事です。質を確保するにはコミュニティの協力による投稿の改善活動が必要です。初心者には「[良い質問をするには?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)」へのリンクを教えて下さい。クラリコメントを投稿し、編集を山ほど推奨してください。

投稿者への悪い印象を与えるのが目的ではなくても、たまになってしまいます。マイナス票は悪用ではなくても、いい気持ちになりません。最終目的（いいプログラミングのリソースになること）を考えながら、自分が出来る範囲で改善をすれば当サイトも進捗します。

Comment: マイナス票が必要なのは同意ですが、この投稿の主旨は **安易にマイナス票が投じられやすい反面質問文を改善する為のコメントが残されない** なのかなと思います（タイトル「質問に対して、反対票を入れる評価基準はありますか？」が少し本題とずれているような気はします）。題材に上がっている質問を例にするとマイナス票が7に対して、質問に対するコメントを残している人は1人（質問の改善に限れば0人）です。**回答に記載しているような質問の改善に繋がるアクションを閲覧者に浸透させるにはどうすれば良いか**といった感じでしょうか。

Comment: むやみにマイナス票を投じるべきでないというのは同意しますが、コメントやクローズといった機能もある中で、マイナス票の使いどころはどういった場面にあるのでしょうか。それと・・・「クラリ」ってなんでしょうか？

Comment: @unarist クラリ=クラリフィケーション（解明するかな？）。投票方法は個人個人で決めることですが、自分では改善できる投稿ならコメントや編集をしてから、投稿者が改善しようとしなかったら後でマイナス票をします。最初からマイナス投票するのは回答が間違っているため、又は質問をどんだけ時間を使って支援しても改善にならないと思う質問です。質問に最初からマイナス票つけるのは非常に少ないですが、クローズ票ができるから代わりにそれを使うことが多いです。

Comment: @ita_3y マイナス票を投票し難くするとマイナス票が減ります。減るとマイナス票の役割ができなくなります。コメント残すことを義務する＝マイナス票を減ることと同じです。ポイントはマイナス票を説明することではなく、質を守りながら、できるだけ悪い印象を与えないことだと思っています。

Answer (score 15):

マイナス票を入れるならコメントを残すべきという意見にはあまり賛成できません。
なぜなら、建設的な批判ができるならマイナス票を入れる必要がないからです。

実際、コメント欄の指摘によって質問が編集されて、質問の質が向上するということは珍しくありません。しかし、そもそもそのような改善の余地が明白な質問にマイナス票はあまり付きません。編集された後でマイナス票を取り消すのも手間でしょうし。

「マイナス票が入っているのにコメントがない」のではなく、「建設的なコメントが困難なのでマイナス票が入っている」というのが実状ではないかと思います。それが良いかどうかは別としても。

**追記:**
さらに、投票に際してコメントを必須とするならば、匿名投票のシステムと矛盾するという問題もあります。

---

また、もとの質問に書かれていた以下の意見も、事実誤認とまでは言いませんがちょっと同意できません。

> また、安易にマイナス票が投じられやすい反面質問文を改善する為のコメントが残されない傾向があります。

質問文を改善する為のコメントはよく行われています。そのような質問は元々の質がそれなりに高いかあるいは、質問の改善によってマイナス票が付いていないので目立たないだけです。そこまで安易にマイナス票が投じられているとは思いません。

もちろん、指摘された-7票の質問の対応に関して問題がないと言うつもりはありませんが、極端なマイナス票のついた質問を引き合いに出してそのような印象を語るのはあまりフェアではないと思いました。

Comment: 論旨前半に賛同できません。理性的な原則論としては、負の評価をする以上は質問者に対する説明責任を持ち、**マイナス票は常に改善コメントとセット**であるべきだと考えます。もちろん別の側面からは、単にコメントする手間が面倒であったり、救いようがない質問（と思える）ことはあります。コメント無しマイナス票のみを是とするのは、極端な例えですが、他者評価プロセスにおいて「あなたは評価に値しない。理由は教えないけどね／自分で考えなさい」という不誠実な態度そのものと考えます。

Comment: 回答者側は、コメントは「質問文を改善する為」やっているかもしれませんが、ニュービーなユーザがそれをどう感じるでしょうかね？日本語版スタックオーバーフローには、そのような上級ユーザとニュービーの意識の差による不愉快さがいっぱいだと思いますよ。まあだからこそ、初心者に対して「良い質問をするには?」のリンクなどを教えてあげるべきなのでしょう。でもそういう行動はあまり見ないしそういうシステムもないようです。・・・いやでもちょっとこれは言い過ぎかな・・・

Comment: @yohjp それは匿名投票システムそのものの否定だと思います。

Comment: @panzer_jagdiron あなたの不満は分かりますが、他のニュービーが同じ不満を持っているとどうして言えるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 9):

当該質問を含め、既に様々なコメントがついている以上、マイナス票しか入れない人にコメントを求めたところで建設的な意見が得られるかどうかは微妙です。

そして「7人がマイナス投票した」というのは、それぐらいは誤差の範囲かなという気がします。当該質問の投稿以降にサイトを訪れた、マイナス投票のできるユーザーは[117名いるようです](http://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/336258)が、ネットユーザーが100人も集まればいろんな意見があるでしょうから・・・。

とはいえ、

> これは質問者を委縮させる結果となり、利用者の減少につながるのではないでしょうか？

という意見には同意します。ですが、ある意味レアケースとも言える7人の存在を論ずるよりも、質問や回答の質を改善し、プラス投票を増やすことを考える方が有意義ではないでしょうか。

ちなみに[スコアがマイナスになっている質問は120件](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20score%3A..-1)、そのうち[12件が未回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20score%3A..-1%20answers%3A0)です。
一方、[スコア0の質問は1,200件](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20score%3A0..0)あり、そのうち[300件が未回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20score%3A0..0%20answers%3A0)です。

スコア0で放置されるのと、マイナス票を入れられるのと、どっちもどっちな気がします。

---

余談ですが、このサイトにもマイナス票のガイドは存在します。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

> プラス投票の権限に集中すべきなので (優れた内容をトップに押し上げます)、そちらが先です。マイナス票は極端な場合のためにとっておいてください。コミュニケーションや編集の代わりを意図するものではありません。
>
> マイナス投票の代わりに
>
> - 投稿がスパムや不快である場合は、通報します。
> - 質問が重複またはトピックから外れている場合は、通報してモデレーターの注意を喚起します。
> - 何かが間違っている場合はコメントを残すか投稿を編集して訂正してください。

上のヘルプ記事からリンクされていますが、質問へのマイナス投票にコストがかからない理由が書かれた公式のブログ記事があります。よろしければこちらも参考までに。

[Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand – Stack Exchange Blog](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)

Comment: マイナス付き未回答の内容を確認しました。以降やクローズや重複などの他に、課題丸投げ、エラーの質問なのにプログラムが書いていないや、一行取り出したものや、製品比較のもの、コメント欄でまずはこれを試してくださいという回答があるもの、大学の研究の質問、画像系プログラムの環境構築のもの、最後のAndroidStudioとページビューコントローラーはなんでマイナスかわかりませんでした。
画像系プログラムの環境構築のものは一見すると目的が不鮮明ですがLinuxでopenCVとffmpegを扱おうとした経験のある人なら遭遇してもおかしくないものだと思いました（しかし、私にはその経験がないので回答できない）。

Answer (score 7):

ある程度の指標があるのでしたら
こんなシステムがあったらいいなというのを書きます

投票者には通報と同じ様に理由が選択できるとコメントの手間が省けますね

質問者には、マイナスの理由が確認できたり
総合値がマイナスに偏った場合、すべての基準を提示するリンクを出せたらいいですね

表現が緩和される事やサイト側からの指示（アカウントの匿名性の為に）とすればコメントファイトが無くなるかと思います。

---

jmacさんの意見には納得できる点があります
しかし、質問の質を上げる以前に回答の質を上げるのが得策かと思われます。

こんな良い回答をしてくれる人がいるならこのサイトを利用しようそう思ってもらえるところが始まりかと思います。

利用者が増えれば、このサイト面白いし勉強になるからと眺めている人達が信用度のためにタグwikiの編集や質問の編集、重複質問の整理などを行うのが理想なのかと思います。

この質問の質を上げるシステムについては長期間回答がなく投票もされない質問に対して投票レビューが行えれば良いのかと思います

Comment: >質問者には、マイナスの理由が確認できたり
>総合値がマイナスに偏った場合、すべての基準を提示するリンクを出せたらいいですね
@natsu ki tinyak
よさそうですね！あればいいなあと思います。

以下蛇足：　私個人の考えとしては、人間の行動はシステムの動きによって、雨樋の上を流れる水のように変化するものと考えています。人間の行動を「心がけ」や「努力」によって変えようとする試みはうまくいかないと思います。それは見た目の上では美しいですが、精神論的で唾棄すべきものだと思います。だからこそ、そのようなシステム上の機能があれかしと思います。

Comment: 「質問の質を上げる以前に回答の質を上げるのが得策」は、「回答の質を上げるためには質問の質を上げるべき」と対立する場合があります。雑なまま改善されていない質問がシンプルにマイナス分類されるシステムを、心地よいと感じる利用者もいます。

Answer (score 6):

元質問に挙げられていた[ランダウの記号の一般的な説明](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/6875/4236)ですが、個人的には質問文を読んでも、付けられたタグ、コメントでのやり取りを見ていても、質問者が回答を欲している印象を受けません。
マイナス票を投じた人にはそれぞれの考え方があるとは思いますが、例えば冷やかし、あるいは荒らしと受け取る人が一定数いたと捉えるのが自然ではないでしょうか？

ただし、質問や回答が理解できないだけでマイナス票を投じる人もいるのは確かで、その点においては安易にマイナスすべきではないとは思います。（質問に対して的確に回答された内容であってもマイナスが投じられることもありますので…）

Answer (score 5):

確かに"安易に反対票と投じる"のは、良い印象は受けないですよね。

でも大切なのは「問題や疑問があったとき、解決するために何か努力をしただろうか」でしょうか。
厳しく見えてしまうかも知れません。ですが、「自分はこのように解決しようと思ったができなかった」「他にも調べてみたけれど、解決には至らなかった」がないと、解決への糸口が自分でつかめないまま、丸投げの質問だらけになりかねないのでは…と。

ソース貼り付けて「動かない！」だけでは、努力してない印象を受けてしまいます。

教える側になっても、教えることで学ぶことがあると、私は思います。
このサイトもその恩恵はありますし、技術者なのでこういう心がけは大切にしたいと思います。

Comment: 「努力」は基準にしたくないです。良い質問は良い質問です。努力しなくても、わかりやすい説明のある質問ならマイナス票を付けなくてもいいと思います。努力と良い質問がつながるケースが多いですが、努力を期待するより、質の良い質問を期待しましょう。

Comment: 確かに「良い質問」は、疑問点が明確ですね。努力だけでは解決しないことも、わかります。質の良い質問を期待しましょう、にはとても賛成です。

Comment: @jmac 「努力」を基準にしたくないという方針であれば、メインサイトのvoteボタンをhoverしたときに表示される文言を早急に変えた方が良いです。努力という文言が一番先に来ているため、voteの判断基準に大きな影響を与えていると思います。up vote：「この質問は実用的である、または分かりやすい」、down vote：「この質問は実用的でない、または分かりにくい」とかですね。

Comment: @kotatsu 同じ疑問は英語版のサイトにもあります。正直にいうと、「努力」で判断するケースは多いですが、「努力」を使うと「努力」を基準にするのは微妙に違うと思います。わかりやすい・実用的であったら、「努力」をあまり気にしないが、ちょっとわかりにくい、ちょっと実用的ではなかったら、努力で判断してしまうケースは多いです。もっといい言い方があればいいですが、英語版では数年間討議しても、もっといい言い方は探せていないですね。

Comment: @jmac そうであれば、せめて文言の順番は変えた方が変えた方が良いと思います。主観的な話をしますが、日本人は「努力」が好きで、「努力していないが、実用的」な質問は信用度がある程度高くないと(その質問の前に相応の実績がないと)良い印象を持たれないと思います。英語版でも疑問があるということは海外でも同じ認識なのでしょうか。

Comment: @kotatsu 英語版では質問が多いため、コミュニティの一部が底質の質問を本当に嫌がっています。そのコミュニティの一部は「努力」を基準にしたいので、あまり優しくないメッセージとかをよく書きました。例えば「代わりにグーグルで検索してあげる」(lmgtfyドットcom)とか、「今まで何をした？」とか、質問の改善につながらないコメントが多かったです。一方では失礼なコメントを避けたいが、他方では底質の質問に努力をしていないから底質になっています。そのためにコメントにlmgtfyドットcomとかのリンクを禁止されていますが、ヘルプの中で[help/mcve]とかを追加して初心者がより高い質の質問をできるように期待しています。