# メタの質問に対しての意見はどう回答すればいいのかわからないのですが。

Tags: 討議, メタ

例えば、

[質問に対して、反対票を入れる評価基準はありますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1876/%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AB%E5%AF%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6-%E5%8F%8D%E5%AF%BE%E7%A5%A8%E3%82%92%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E8%A9%95%E4%BE%A1%E5%9F%BA%E6%BA%96%E3%81%AF%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)

は、日本でスタックオーバーフローが流行るか否かの重要な議論のように思えます。
自分も少しアイデアがあるのですが、それを

- 回答として記述すればよいのか
- 質問へのコメントとして記述すればよいのか
- 新しい質問として投稿すればよいのか

よくわかりません。

実際どうするのが良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

メタにおける「質問」は議題・トピック・スレッドなどと呼ばれるようなものです。ですから、**その質問への返答、その議題における一意見は基本的に「回答」として投稿します。**

このため、メインサイトでの投票は投稿の質や正しさに対して行いますが、メタではそれぞれの意見に賛成か反対かという表明として使われることが多いです。多数決ではありませんが。

コメントについても基本的にはメインサイトと同じように考えればいいと思います。

[ヘルプ センター > 権限 > どこでもコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

> 次のような場合はコメントを送信してください。
>
> - 作成者に対して明確化をリクエストする
> - 作成者が投稿を改善するのに役立つ建設的な批判を残す
> - 関係するがささいまたは一時的な情報を投稿に追加する (関係する質問へのリンク、または質問が更新されたことを作成者に知らせる、など)

ただし、議題が変わる・派生する場合、あるいは一つの意見に対してコメントでの議論が盛んな場合は、改めて「質問」として投稿したほうがいいかもしれません。

- 元の議題に対する話と混ざることを避けられる
- 別のタイトル・タグを付けられ、質問一覧やサイドバーに表示される
- コメントと違って回答にはプラス・マイナス投票、そして更なるコメントができる