# 質問の投票ボタン：努力した跡がみられる、実用的で分かりやすく書かれている

Tags: 討議, 日本語, 投票の仕方

先日、メタ投稿「[質問に対して、反対票を入れる評価基準はありますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1876)」が話題になりましたが、[コメントで](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1876/#comment1063_1886)こんなやり取りがありました。

> 「努力」は基準にしたくないです。良い質問は良い質問です。努力しなくても、わかりやすい説明のある質問ならマイナス票を付けなくてもいいと思います。努力と良い質問がつ‌​ながるケースが多いですが、努力を期待するより、質の良い質問を期待しましょう。 –  jmac♦
>
> @jmac 「努力」を基準にしたくないという方針であれば、メインサイトのvoteボタンをhoverしたときに表示される文言を早急に変えた方が良いです。努力という文言が一番先‌​に来ているため、voteの判断基準に大きな影響を与えていると思います。up vote：「この質問は実用的である、または分かりやすい」、down vote：「この質問は実用的でない、または分かりにくい」とかですね。 –  kotatsu

質問のプラス・マイナス投票ボタンにカーソルを乗せると、以下のツールチップが表示されます。

> この質問には解決しようと努力した跡がみられる・実用的で分かりやすく書かれている
>   この質問には解決しようと努力した跡がみられない・実用的ではない・分かりにくい

このツールチップも英語版から翻訳したものです。しかし今や膨大なユーザーと質問を抱える英語版と、現在の日本語版では事情も違いますから、同じ文章にする必要もないと思います。

日本語版ではどんな文章がいいと思いますか？あるいは今のままがいいでしょうか？

もちろんこの文章が絶対的なルールというわけではないですし、そもそも気にしたことがないという人もいるとは思いますが、迷った時の参考程度にはなるかなと思っています。

### あわせて読みたい

- [ヘルプセンター > 投票が重要なのはなぜ?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)
- [権限 > プラス投票する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) と [権限 > マイナス投票する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)
- [そうだ、投票しよう！ - スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1528)

Comment: > 「膨大なユーザーと質問を抱える英語版と、現在の日本語版では事情も違いますから」
私も同じことを感じています。日本語版はスタートアップ段階あるわけですから、英語版の(質の低い)質問の多さに対応した少し厳しい文章は、今の段階では緩和した方が良いと思っています。これは「[市民の努め(Civic Duty)](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty)」バッジの取得者数の少なさと無関係ではないと思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

英語版の原文はまったく見ずに書いていますが、次のような文言はどうでしょうか。

- この質問は、趣旨が明確でわかりやすい・実用的である・建設的である
- この質問は、調査や試行錯誤の跡がまったくない・内容がたいへん杜撰である

一応、以下を参考にしました。

[どのような質問は避けるべきですか? - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
[良い質問をするには? - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
[権限 - 反対投票する - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

努力を基準にしたくないというのは同意しますが、それはあくまでプラス票のときの話だと思います。ですのでマイナス票にのみ、努力の具体的な方向性を明示する文言を入れてみました。[良い質問をするには?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)では冒頭で検索して調べることを勧めていますし、[反対投票する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)でも何かしらの努力は要求されていることも考慮しています。

一方で、わかりやすさの観点についてはマイナス票から外しています。そういう質問にはまずコメント欄で修正を促すか、あるいは編集権の所有者が編集してしまう方が良いと思われるからです。

プラス票のときとマイナス票のときで、評価軸が対称である必要もないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: [この質問](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/10968/)は当サイトで３番目プラス票が多いですが、「調査や試行錯誤の跡がまったくない」が当てはまります。このような質問は努力しなくても、いいリソースになります。もしそのマイナス票の案内を入れたら、悪影響は出ないのでしょうか？

Comment: ご指摘の質問は少なくともgitのドキュメントに目を通し、どこを読んだのかを特定した上でリンクを張って質問されていますので、少なくとも調査が行われた形跡が見られるものと考えていいのではないでしょうか。「努力がなくても良い質問は存在する」という@jmac氏の見解には基本的に異論はありません。要はプラスとマイナスのバランスだと考えます。一つの質問の中にプラス要素とマイナス要素が共存していることがほとんどです。仮に努力が見られなくとも建設的とか有用とかいう側面が大きければプラス票を投じる人が増えるでしょう。上記の質問は単なる検索では回答が得られにくい類の質問に思えますので、プラス票が多かったのではないかと推測します。

Comment: 提案した文言には、安直にマイナスが入れられないように「まったく」とか「たいへん」といった強調を意図的に付け加えたつもりです。

Answer (score 6):

なかなか回答が付かないので僭越ながら。

コメントを見る限り、現時点では「努力の有無」は判断基準として重視しない方針ということですので、やはり該当部分を削除するのが適切かなと思いました。

```
この質問は疑問点、問題点が分かりやすく書かれている・実用的である
この質問は疑問点、問題点が不明瞭であり改善が必要である・実用的ではない
```

「改善が必要である」と書くとクローズとの違いが曖昧になる気がしますが、マイナス票は入れられるが、クローズ票は入れられないユーザもいるので、書いても良いかなと思いました。

「疑問点、問題点」の部分は他に適切な言い方がありそうな気がしています（「聞きたい事」とか？）。

Answer (score 0):

試行錯誤の場合、編集自体を試行錯誤と考える人も出てきます。
むしろ、この部分が改善されれば良い質問の基準悪い質問の基準がはっきりしツアーの記述が少し変わり初めての質問者でも利用しやすくなると思います。

- ↑知りたい、良い回答があった。コンテンツとして面白い。
- ↓情報が不足している、多くの人が知っている。日本語ではない

基礎がないのに調べているなどで質問が飛躍している人には情報が不足しているでは伝わらないこともあるので、もっと具体的にすると

- ↓コードが必要、エラーが記述がない、文面では伝わりにくい、詳細仕様が不足している

多くの人が知っているはコンテンツとして面白いの逆です。←回答まで含めて見た時ということです。多くの人が知っておりありきたりな回答がなされている場合そのコンテンツ質問はユニークではなく面白みを感じないと思います。

最後の日本語ではないについては
英語の質問と回答はマイナス票でも良いかと個人的には思っています。無茶苦茶で強引な引用の仕方かもしれませんが

> [日本語版Stack Overflowのターゲットユーザーである、「日本語を話すプログラマー」です。][1]

Comment: 質問への投票は、質問の質を評価するものだと思っています。そのため、（結果的にそれが基準になりがちであっても）「自分が共感したか・興味があるかどうか」「面白いと感じるかどうか」という主観的なものを投票の基準として提示することには疑問を覚えます。「多くの人が知っている」は例えば[該当分野では基礎的とされる質問](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1595)でしょうか？リンク先で論じられている通り、これも一概に質が低いとは言えません。

Comment: そして英語の質問についてですが、仮に「日本語話者がメインターゲットであり、英語の質問はそれに該当しない」とした場合、英語の質問はオフトピックということになると思います（引用元の質問でもオフトピックかどうかという話ですね）。その上で、あなたがマイナス投票すべきと考えておられるのは英語の質問だけですか？それともオフトピック全般ですか？

Comment: @unarist オフトピはマイナス票か通報かどちらが良いかという点は両方を同時に行う必要があると思います。 うえについては追記しました[編集履歴](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/1974/revisions)が追加部分で‌​す。